# Forcing class inheritance in c++11 for wrapped classes -- is it a bad thing?

Tags: c++, c++11, multiple-inheritance, word-wrap

I've been working on a wrapping library for scripted languages (partially to learn c++11 features, and partially for a specific need). One issue that has come up is that of exporting inherited objects to the scripted language.

The problem involves using proxy objects of wrapped classes for the invocation of functions. Specifically, if a function takes a `Foo *`, then the object proxy from whatever scripted language is being used must be cast appropriately.

There are two ways (that I can think of) to model the object proxy appropriately:

```
template <class T>
struct ObjectProxy {
   T *ptr;
};
```

or:

```
struct WrappedClass {
  virtual ~WrappedClass() {}
};

struct ObjectProxy {
  WrappedClass *ptr;

  template <typename T>
  boost::shared_ptr<T> castAs() {
    return boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(instance);
  }
};
```

The problem with the first version is that you need to know ahead of time what type `ObjectProxy` is pointing to. Unfortunately, there is no easy solutions to this (see many of my previous questions). After some investigation, it looks like most of the popular libraries that do this (e.g. boost::python, LuaBind, etc.) keep a graph of all the class relationships in order to allow for the proper casting.

The second method avoid having to do all that, but does add the constraint that every class you wrap must inherit from WrappedClass.

Here's my question: can anyone think of any major problems, besides being slightly annoying to the user, with the second approach? Even if you didn't make a specific class, you should always be able to subclass it. For example, if you had some library the provide class `Foo`, then you could do:

```
class FooWrapped: public Foo, public WrappedClass {};
```

This does make things a little less seamless for the user (though I've been looking into ways of automating this), it does mean you can rely on the built-in dynamic_cast rather than having to write your own variant.

**edit**

Added `castAs()` to make use-case clearer

Comment: You can't use `dynamic_cast` unless `WrappedClass` has at least one virtual function (e.g. `public: virtual ~WrappedClass() = 0;`).

Comment: You are right. I left that out in my attempts to simplify. Fixing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like what [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html) was designed to solve.  The solution basically combines your two ideas: (code untested)

```
struct ObjectProxyBase {
  virtual ~ObjectProxyBase() {}
};

template <class T>
struct ObjectProxy : public ObjectProxyBase {
   T *ptr;
};

template <class T>
T *proxy_cast(ObjectProxyBase *obj) {
    auto ptr = dynamic_cast<ObjectProxy<T> *>(obj);
    if (!ptr)
        return nullptr;

    return ptr->ptr;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. The problem is that the dynamic cast from ObjectProxy<A> to ObjectProxy<B> will fail, even if A inherits from B (I can post example code if you want). I played around with using `boost::any`, but the problem is it only has a `static_cast`. Someone made a version that does `dynamic_cast`, but I couldn't get it to work.